# Avoid .desktop terminal starter to be in same group as other terminal windows in (gnome and other) window managers

Tags: terminal, window-manager, .desktop

I made a custom .desktop file and put it into .local/share/applications. Now I can run it from desktop menus like gnome shell. The content is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Todovim
GenericName=Todovim
Comment=Open my todo file in vim with vim-todo plugin
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=todovim
Categories=Utility;Terminal
Keywords=Todo;Terminal
Exec=xfce4-terminal -e "tmux new-session 'zsh -ic todoedit ; read'" --hide-menubar --hide-toolbar --hide-scrollbar --maximize
Type=Application
Icon=trine
```

But when starting the app, it gets grouped to other terminal windows -- I want to have it separate from those. How to avoid grouping and keep it in its own separate application group?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `xfce4-terminal` with `sudo` for the current user, this will start a new instance.

```
sudo -E -u current-user xfce4-terminal
```

Replace the `Exec` line with the following (replace `current-user` with your username)

```
Exec=sudo -E -u current-user xfce4-terminal -e "tmux new-session 'zsh -ic todoedit ; read'" --hide-menubar --hide-toolbar --hide-scrollbar --maximize
```

You can as well use sudo without `-E` option if you don't want to use the current environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I’ve understood, the `StartupWMClass` setting will not *configure* the window class of the starting application.

Instead, it tells the desktop environment what to expect: ”Once a window with *this* window class appears, you can consider the start-up of this item completed, and end the start-up notification for it.”

But sine you’ve disabled the startup notification, the `StartupWMClass` setting will have no effect at all.

Instead, you should add a `—window` option to the `xfce4-terminal` command line to specify that you want this command run in a separate window:

```
Exec=xfce4-terminal --window -e "tmux new-session 'zsh -ic todoedit ; read'" --hide-menubar --hide-toolbar --hide-scrollbar --maximize
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I could not reproduce any of the answers. I found a way to get it to work with the Terminal Emulator [Alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty):

It has an option to set the window class with the `--class` option. If you set it to be the same class as the StartupWMClass of the .desktop file, it will spawn with a separate icon (at least in Gnome on wayland). Now the launcher file looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Todovim
GenericName=Todovim
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Utility
Keywords=Todo
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Todovim
Exec=alacritty --class Todovim -e zsh -ic todoedit
Type=Application
Icon=trine
Name[de_DE.UTF-8]=todovim
```

I also changed Terminal to false, as it would launch a second terminal window.